# Remove a string which is not present in parenthesis ()?

Tags: sed

I have a file which consist a data as below, and I want to remove which data   not present 
in the parenthesis.

```
 hello (welcome) to chennai (hai)
 hello (how) this is for testing (with) 
 [is] this (bhuvanesh)
```

I want the output as below

```
(welcome) (hai)
 (how) (with)
 (bhuvanesh)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following sed command:

```
sed 's/[^(]*\(([^)]\+)\)[^(]*/\1/g' input.txt
```

**Explanation:**

I'm using the substitute command. In it's basic form it looks like this:

```
s/SEARCH/REPLACE/g
```

the `g` at end the means *global*, and means sed should reaplace all occurences of `SEARCH` not just the first.

The `SEARCH` pattern looks like this:

```
[^(]*\(([^)]\+)\)[^(]*
```

I'll try to explain it step by step...

```
[^(]*
```

`[]` is a character class, the `^` at the beginning means that the characters listed in the class should *not* match. We are listing only a single character - the opening parenthesis `(`. The `*` means this can occur zero or more times. In one sentence, sed is searching for all characters before the first starting parenthesis `(`.

```
\(([^)]\+)\)
```

`(...)` is a matching group. In the basic sed language it needs to get escaped: `\(...\)`. The first character in the matching group is the opening parenthesis `(`. A character class `[^)]` is following. It matches every character except of the closing parenthesis `)`. The quantifier `\+` means there must be at least one character between the parenthesises in your input text, if you would like to allow empty content you need to use the `*` as quantifier here. It follows the closing parenthesis `)` and the end of the matching group `\)`..

Through the usage of the matching group, the matched content is available via `\1` now.

The last part of the search pattern is the same as the first part:

```
[^(]*
```

It matches everything until the next opening parenthesis.

The `REPLACE` pattern is simple. It throws away everything except of the content of matching group `\1`.

Comment: It is not working yeah..?

Comment: Are using MacOS? Meaning BSD sed?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Oh good. I have tested it on Linux. What is exactly not working?

Comment: Oh sorry yeah. just now only i saw that by mistake i give wrong file..I am really sorry and Thank you for your response

Comment: Yeah.. it is working correctly, but it also having a some mistake when my string present like this  `(welcome ` this doesn't remove this

Comment: Ok Thank you, but if you have a time , then you take this one

Comment: Is it safe, that between parenthesis can only occure a word, meaning no spaces?

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` would do:

```
awk -F"[()]" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "(%s) ",$i;print ""}' file
(welcome) (hai)
(how) (with)
(bhuvanesh)
```

Or like this:

```
awk -F"[()]" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
welcome hai
how with
bhuvanesh
```

Comment: i need answer in sed

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

`sed -r 's/\[.*\][^(]*//g ; s/.*(\(.*\)).*(\(.*\))/\1\2/g'`

Comment: your just send a command for my input only but i need if its present where ever in my file.. and it also more complicated

Comment: @Bhuvanesh That's what your question!!!

Comment: This is  sample question, But my question is i want to remove the string which is not present in the parenthesis